# Animating N points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, data, animation

So I'm trying to create an animation of N interacting particles in two dimensions confined in a box. Generating the data is fine and it's being stored in a text file with two columns for each particle; one for its x coordinate and one for y. At the moment this is the code I've got to animate 4 particles, so a file with 8 columns:

```
data = Import["many_particles.txt", "Table"];
Animate[Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Red, 
   Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}], PointSize[0.025], Blue, 
   Point[{data[[i, 3]], data[[i, 4]]}], PointSize[0.025], Green, 
   Point[{data[[i, 5]], data[[i, 6]]}], PointSize[0.025], Pink, 
   Point[{data[[i, 7]], data[[i, 8]]}]}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, Frame -> True], {i, 1, 3000, 1}, 
   AnimationRate -> 30, AnimationRunning -> True]
```

And that gives me a visual result that I like, but I'd like to be able to import a data file with any number of columns (so any number of particles), and be able to animate them without writing a ridiculously long animate function to account for every one.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Harry

Comment: Use `Partition` to break the list onto coordinate pairs, and exploit the fact that `Point` can contain more than a single point, i.e. `Point[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}]` is valid. Also, consider `ListAnimate` instead of `Animate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous method I posted used `ListPlot` to generate the frames for the animation, but this is a very slow way to do it if you want to animate thousands of frames.  A much quicker way is to just use graphics primitives like in the original post.

Here is a very fast function that will animate an unknown number of particles.  I found that using `ListAnimate` slowed down the execution considerably over `Animate`, so that is what is used here.  Keep in mind, it's usually better to use `ListAnimate` as it compiles the entire animation before showing it to you so it can handle errors better.  When toying around here, I had initially neglected to have `Animate` only vary the parameter `n` by integer values, and this made my notebook nearly unresponsive.  It's also possible that `ListAnimate` and `Animate` use different amounts of memory, but I'm not certain of that.

```
animation[datalist_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{point, data2, nparticles, colorlist, imglist, opts, prange},

  (*A simple function to create the graphics primitives*) 
  point[color_, coords_] := {PointSize[0.025], color, Point[coords]};

  (*Partition the data into the right dimensionality*)

  data2 = Partition[#, 2] & /@ datalist;

  (*Generate a list of distinct colors for every particle*)

  nparticles = Length@data2[[1]];
  colorlist = Hue /@ Range[0, 1., 1./nparticles][[2 ;;]];

  (*Generate the list of images*)

  prange = {#, #} &@Through[{Max, Min}[datalist]];
  imglist = 
   Graphics[point @@@ Transpose[{colorlist, #}], 
      Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Graphics]]], 
      PlotRange -> prange] & /@ data2;

  (*Animate the list of images - 
  the slower `ListAnimate` is commented out in favor of the more primitive `Animate` *)
  (*ListAnimate[imglist]*)
  Animate[imglist[[n]], {n, 1, Length@imglist, 1}, 
   AnimationRate -> 30, AnimationRunning -> True]
  ]
```

This can work on OP's data set in about 0.06 seconds on my machine (versus about 50 seconds for the `ListPlot` solution)

```
opdata = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6sccqHr8", "Table"];

animation[opdata, BaseStyle -> 20, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

You can even apply it to a list with 60 particles, and still less than half a second

```
randomdata = 
  Transpose[
   Table[Accumulate[
     Prepend[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3000}], 
      RandomReal[{-10, 10}]]], {2*60}]];
animation[randomdata, BaseStyle -> 20, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Of course, if you want to export the animation for viewing outside the notebook, I would definitely recommend exporting the individual frames as image files and converting them using another program.  Mathematica is not great at outputting movie files in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is certainly works but I'm finding that it takes an awfully long time to run and uses up a lot of memory. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Which step takes a long time?  Generating the test data, creating the plots, or the final `ListAnimate` command?  I was able to do it all in under 30 seconds on a fresh kernel

Comment: I'm using my own data now. I commented out the list animate and it still took a while, but it seems that the list animate is where the bulk of the time is taken

Comment: Maybe we should adjourn to the chatroom?  I could help more, but it will take more specifics and the little icon always pops up here saying to avoid prolonged discussions in the comments section

Comment: Anyway, if you can point me to your data, maybe put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) I can look at how long it takes to make the animation.  What is your end goal of the animation?  To look at in the notebook or to export it to a file to view outside of Mathematica?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6sccqHr8 There's the link to the data I'm using at the moment for 4 particles (not familiar with pastebin so let me know if I've messed up). At the moment it's just to look at in the notebook but who knows what the future might hold. Thanks!

Comment: Re. creating a movie [MathMF](https://github.com/SimonWoods/MathMF) can be used on Windows. As long as all frames can be kept at once in the memory I don't see a problem with Mathematica's built-in capabilities though.

Comment: I usually like to export frames and then use ffmpeg to convert to video